# Can I use phpmyadmin with visual c++?

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, phpmyadmin

I am currently working with visual c++ to make GUI's and require a database to store some of the data, I have been using MySql but whilst searching for information on this I keep running into phpmyadmin, from what I have read this is a browser based MySql management tool, if this is correct then my question becomes, is this something I could use with visual c++ to manage my database and is this the preferred way of using database's with visual c++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`phpmyadmin` is strictly web-based. You are dealing with client c++.

Answer (score 0):

No it is a admin tool. It is not a programmers tool.  See this [visual c++ 2010 mysql connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605672/visual-c-2010-mysql-connect) link for more information.